# Why fill() , copy() ,reverse() and shuffle() of Collections in java is implemented this way

Tags: java, performance, list, collections, iterator

According to javadoc... Collections.fill() is written as below :

```
public static <T> void fill(List<? super T> list, T obj) {
        int size = list.size();

        if (size < FILL_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
                list.set(i, obj);
        } else {
            ListIterator<? super T> itr = list.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {
                itr.next();
                itr.set(obj);
            }
        }
    }
```

Its easy to understand why they didn't use listIterator for

```
if (size < FILL_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess)
```

condition as of RandomAccess. But whats the use of `size < FILL_THRESHOLD` in above?

I mean is there any significant performance benefit over using `iterator` for `size>=FILL_THRESHOLD` and not for `size < FILL_THRESHOLD` ?

I see the same approach for Collections.copy() also :

```
 public static <T> void copy(List<? super T> dest, List<? extends T> src) {
        int srcSize = src.size();
        if (srcSize > dest.size())
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Source does not fit in dest");

        if (srcSize < COPY_THRESHOLD ||
            (src instanceof RandomAccess && dest instanceof RandomAccess)) {
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++)
                dest.set(i, src.get(i));
        } else {
            ListIterator<? super T> di=dest.listIterator();
        ListIterator<? extends T> si=src.listIterator();
            for (int i=0; i<srcSize; i++) {
                di.next();
                di.set(si.next());
            }
        }
    }
```

FYI:

```
 private static final int FILL_THRESHOLD           =   25;

 private static final int COPY_THRESHOLD           =   10;
```

Same Approach for below :

```
 public static void reverse(List<?> list)
 public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd)
```

**EDIT :**

My confusion is for `size<FILL_THRESHOLD` part , not for `RandomAccess`

Comment: Are you confused because there are two different thresholds insted of one?

Comment: @Mirko : Not at all because of that. I can understand it very well that both the method has different requirements.So two different thresholds makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this is because a generic list is not meant to be an `ArrayList`. There is no guarantee that setting a random index is done in constant *O(1)* time. At the same time building an iterator and working over it has its overhead.

In conclusion for small lists you can sacrifice the fact that using an iterator would give a lower complexity for accessing consecutive elements, by saving the overhead of creating the iterator itself.

This because `list.set(i, obj)` can be more expensive then `itr.set(obj)` but in the latter you would have implicit overhead of managing the iterator. Since complexity can be linear *O(n)*, using `list.set(i, obj)` for larger lists could be effectively a problem.

Comment: And I suppose they arrived at the values for these thresholds after benchmarking how LinkedList (the other List implementation in the JDK) fares.

Comment: _"There is no guarantee that accessing a random index is done in constant O(1) time"_ that's true, but [the `RandomAccess` marker interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) on a `List` implementation indicates _"that [the implementation] supports fast (generally constant time) random access."_

Comment: @Matt Ball: Yes, but we are talking here about the case where it is not a RandomAccess. For RandomAccess, an iterator is never used.

Comment: @MattBall: that's it. But that is not the point: even with lists which are not `RandomAccess`, managing an iterator when copying or filling small lists is more expensive than blindly copying them, even if the operation is not *O(1)*.

Comment: @Thilo: That's what I'd expect from Java developers :)

Answer (score 1):

Java 1.2, which introduced the collection framework, and Java 1.3 used the straightforward approach with a ListIterator:

```
public static void fill(List list, Object o) {
    for (ListIterator i = list.listIterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {
        i.next();
        i.set(o);
    }
}
```

The thresholds were introduced alongside the [RandomAccess](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/RandomAccess.html) marker interface in Java 1.4 (all based on the legacy code for the JDK from Oracle's website).

I think that this is an optimization older garbage collection algorithms - these older algorithms had rather [heavy penalties for creating a new object](http://oreilly.com/catalog/javapt/chapter/ch04.html) (such as a ListIterator). Therefore, using setters for non-O(1)-lists made sense.

Rather ironically, *Java 1.4.1* introduced a new garbage collector that made object creation much cheaper for short lived objects such as an iterator.